# MVC CheckBox change event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, checkbox

I am new to MVC so I think I need to be pointed in the right direction.

I have a boolean in my model which creates a checkbox in my view using:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adults)
```

I also have a dropdownbox which shows content from a ViewBag. I want to show different ViewBag sets depending on the condition of that checkbox.

I can do it by checking my mode.Adults variable using Razor syntax in my html, but this will only work on my edit page, not on the create page. Also, it will not work when I click on the checkbox (I would need it reloaded with new values in the dropdown list).

I was hoping to avoid posting back to the server using jQuery, and instead do it all client side. However if this is the ONLY way to do it, can someone help on HOW to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was hoping to avoid posting back to the server using jQuery, and
>   instead do it all client side.

You could have the 2 lists serialized directly into your view. And then subscribe to the `.change` event of the checkbox and switch the dropdown values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This assumes that ViewBag.List1 and ViewBag.List2 are IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
    var list1 = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.List1);
    var list2 = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.List2);

    $(function() {
        $('#Adults').change(function() {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            setDropDownValues(checked);
        });
    });

    function setDropDownValues(checked) {
        var dropDown = $('#id_of_your_drop_down');
        dropDown.empty();
        var list = checked ? list1 : list2;
        $.each(list, function() {
            dropDown.append('<option/>', {
                value: this.Value,
                html: this.Text
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like what I need! How do I know the ID of my dropdown and the ID of the checkbox if they are dynamically created?

Comment: You could explicitly set them: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SomeProperty, Model.SomeCollection, new { id = "some_id" })`. For the CheckBox you seem to be using EditorFor which doesn't allow you to set html attributes. You could either wrap it in a `<div>` with a specific id and then adapt your selector, or write a custom editor template which will allow you to set the id.

Comment: The ID seems to be generated at runtime as the name of the variable it is an editor for. So in this case Adults. However the function doesn't seem to fire on the change. Do I need to add something else?

Comment: Thanks for your solution Darin. I figured out what was going on with my scenario, and it was that the lists I had contained custom classes. So I used `Json.Encode(@ViewBag.List1)`.